# Multi-class oversampling based online bagging

Tags: multiclass-classification, ensemble-learning, imbalanced-data, oversampling

can anyone give me MOOB code in python

Multi-class classication problems are often considered more challenging than their binary
counterparts because multiple classes can increase the data complexity and aggravate the
imbalanced distribution
A limited number of research studies considered multi-class online learning from evolving
streams, focusing on resampling techniques. Two ensemble learning methods for multi-class online learning have been proposed.
These two algorithms, Multi-class Oversampling-based Online Bagging (MOOB) and Multi-
class Under-sampling-based Online Bagging (MUOB) use re-sampling to overcome class
imbalance, with the framework of Online Bagging (OB)

I need code of Multi-class oversampling based online bagging (MOOB) for multiclass imbalance data handling.